# Grep invert match with context

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep a file with invert match, but also not match every line occurring right after the matching lines.

So I have the following contents in a file called `testing_grep`:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddddddd
llllllllllllllllll
dddddddddddddddddd
llllllllllllllllll
fffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffff
```

So I want to match all lines except the ones containing `d` and the next line following such a match, so I have the following `grep` command:

```
 grep -v "d" -A 1 testing_grep.txt
```

However, I still get all lines being outputed while all I need is the following output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccc
fffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffff
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with GNU sed:

In pattern space (current line) search (`//`) a line containg `d`. Only for those lines append the next line of input into the pattern space (`N`) and delete pattern space (`d`).

```
sed '/d/{N;d;}' testing_grep.txt
```

Output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccc
fffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus already got you the perfect answer, but if you wana do it with grep ( which is more complicated)

you grep the lines you do not want and you put them in a file:

`grep 'd' -A 1 testing_grep.txt > otherfile.txt`

otherfile.txt content will be :

`dddddddddddddddddd
llllllllllllllllll
dddddddddddddddddd
llllllllllllllllll`

Then you use the diff command to get the difference:

`diff testing_grep.txt otherfile.txt | grep '^[<>]'`